# Difference between sails lift and node app.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

What is the difference between starting an app with 
`sails lift` and node `app.js`? 
And which one is best to use for production enviroments?

Answer (score 1):

`sails lift` gives you an ability to restart on files change. With `node app.js` you should rerun application after every change. They also said:  startup time is decreased, but I can't guaranty that:)

But for production you need a process manager. Something like `pm2`. You can find more information in the repo: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

For development purpose you can use http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-development/
It will restart the application on every code change

Comment: I agree cannot use it 'directly', but still use pm2 start app.js or for sails pm2 start app.js -x -- --prod?  should I update the question? (I didn't want to dive into a specific like pm2 though)

Comment: Thanks that does clarify things. I found something that might be worth mentioning as well: http://ash.zi.vc/sails/2016/02/08/a-better-way-of-deploying-your-sailsjs-application-to-a-production-environment/   Seems to indicate that the startup time is also much better, decreasing possible issues during restarts etc. Double check me and add it in maybe.